# adding a title when downloading div as image with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, text, html2canvas

I have a function that uses html2canvas to download a few divs as images. I want to be able to also add a title at the top of the image when its saved, which would be the chartColumnID.

```
  function saveAsImage(chartColumnID){
            html2canvas($('#'+ chartColumnID),
            {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    a.download = chartColumnID;
                    a.click();
                }
             });
            };
```

I've tried something like this but it doesnt work, no title appears. ive moved the a.text= to different lines to double check if i was maybe putting it in the wrong place but no luck.

```
 function saveAsImage(chartColumnID){
            html2canvas($('#'+ chartColumnID),
            {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    a.download = chartColumnID;
                    a.text= (15, 15, chartColumnID.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim());
                    a.click();
                }
             });
            };
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to make the chart column id a title also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try drawing a text on a canvas (I did not checked that):

```js
function saveAsImage(chartColumnID) {
  html2canvas($('#' + chartColumnID), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
// ----------------------------- here we draw text:
      const fontHeight = 14;
      const text = String(chartColumnID);
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.font = fontHeight + "px Arial";
      ctx.textAlign = "left";
      ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // text color
      ctx.fillText(text, 0, fontHeight);
// ------------------------------ your code as ususal:
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      a.download = chartColumnID;
      a.click();
    }
  });
};
```

Example of how it should look like on canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var chartColumnID = (Math.random() * 1000 + 1) | 0;
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

const fontHeight = 14;
const text = String(chartColumnID);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = fontHeight + "px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // text color
ctx.fillText(text, 0, fontHeight);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" />
```